# Как изменить стиль элементу на javascript?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Хочу поменять стиль элементу на странице, который соответствует выбранному (у них одинаковый параметр idEv). Пробую так:

```
 function xxx()
    {
        var tt = PF('timelineVar');
        var selEv = tt.getSelectedEvent();
        var idSelEv = selEv.idEv;

        var dt = tt.getData();
        dt = JSON.parse(dt);
        var x = dt.length;

        while (x--) {
          if (dt[x].idEv === idSelEv) {
             dt[x].className = "out";
          }
      }
```

Я так подозреваю, что нужно либо обновить полностью элемент `tt`, который содержит эти элементы. Либо напрямую заломиться именно к нужному мне элементу, чтобы поменять ему стиль, но как?
Я не знаю его id, чтобы воспользоваться `getElementById(value)`. И я не уверен, что есть какая то принудительная обновлялка элементов, чтобы полностью обновить `tt`. Что посоветуете?

Comment: что такое `PF`? что такое `tt`? Что такое `dt`? Что такое `dt[x]`?

Answer (score 1):

что бы достучаться до инлайновых стилей нужно делать так

```
elementDom.style.color='red';
elementDom.style.backgroundColor='aliceblue';
```

фишку только надо уловить если `background-color` то надо делать `backgroundColor`